# importing issues between modules

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.5

```
|--------FlaskApp
|----------------FlaskApp
|----------------__init__.py
|----------------view.py
|----------------models.py
|----------------db_create.py
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
|----------------flaskapp.wsgi
```

this is my modules and folder layout i have a import problem in init i have

```
db = sqlalchemy
```

im trying to import **db** to **views.py, models.py and db_create.py** but im getting all kinds of importing errors because im not importing thr proper way now my question is if i want to import db to the modules i specified how would i do it without getting a error

**some of the code importing db**

**models.py**

```
from FlaskApp import db

class UserInfo(db.Model):

__tablename_ = 'user_info'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
posts = relationship('UserPosts', backref='posts')

def __init__(self, username, email, password):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.username, self.email)
```

**views.py**

```
from FlaskApp import db

@app.route('/')
@login_required     
def home():
    user = db.session.query(UserInfo).all()
    return render_template('home.html', user=user)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925573 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925618 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 14, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925626 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925638 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925644 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]     import FlaskApp.main, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925653 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/main.py", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925658 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]     from models import UserInfo, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925668 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/models.py", line 2, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925673 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884]     from FlaskApp import db, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Oct 11 04:17:20.925707 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 5049:tid 139870897813248] [client 174.58.31.189:55884] ImportError: cannot import name 'db', referer: http://localhost/
```

my goal is not just to solve one error is to be able to import the right way from now on

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the most painful moment for a Flask learner. Basically, your `FlaskApp` is dependent on `FlaskApp.main` then `FlaskApp.models` and then back to `FlaskApp` which create a perfect case of circular dependency.

Here's the way which I think is elegant and pythonic, by attaching the `db` variable to `app` in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.db = db

with app.app_context():
    import FlaskApp.main
```

In `main.py`:

```
from flask import current_app as app
from .models import UserInfo


@app.route('/')
@login_required     
def home():
    user = app.db.session.query(UserInfo).all()
    return render_template('home.html', user=user)
```

In `models.py`:

```
from flask import current_app as app

db = app.db


class UserInfo(db.Model):

    __tablename_ = 'user_info'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    posts = relationship('UserPosts', backref='posts')

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.username, self.email)
```

Then you can use `app.db` or `current_app.db` inside of any functions/methods in your application and don't need to worry about the circular dependency.

Comment: Ill give this a try

Comment: If i try to use the lazy way i still get cannot import name db in models.py and im not sure how to use your second suggestion

Comment: @quechon I edited the answer. Just forget about the lazy loading way it actually requires more tricky works to load the models.

Answer (score 0):

got this after using the above answer

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the documentation for more information.
```

```
    tail -n 40 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315500 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     import FlaskApp.main
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315510 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/main.py", line 2, in <module>
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315516 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     from .models import UserInfo
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315526 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/models.py", line 7, in <module>
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315532 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     db = app.db
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315542 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315547 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315557 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315563 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     return self.__local()
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315573 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 51, in _find_app
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315579 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784]     raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315611 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315620 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] 
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315634 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315641 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.315648 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19327:tid 139821662463744] [client 174.58.31.189:51784] documentation for more information.
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.813916 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] mod_wsgi (pid=19326): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814030 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] mod_wsgi (pid=19326): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814917 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814972 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 14, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814981 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814993 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.814998 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     import FlaskApp.main, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815008 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/main.py", line 2, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815014 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     from .models import UserInfo, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815024 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/models.py", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815029 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     db = app.db, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815040 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815046 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name), referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815055 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815061 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     return self.__local(), referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815071 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 51, in _find_app, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815077 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786]     raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg), referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815107 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] RuntimeError: Working outside of application context., referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815114 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] , referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815118 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815123 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815139 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Oct 12 00:20:02.815143 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19326:tid 139821670856448] [client 174.58.31.189:51786] documentation for more information., referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace? You need to put all related imports inside of `app_context`. I can't help without more information.

Comment: just added the stacktrace

Comment: The stacktrace is too short and it doesn't contain the problem point. Please ensure the log result started with something like "Traceback (most recent call last)".

Comment: how can i get a longer one from apache2

Comment: use `tail -n 40 /var/log/apache2/error.log`. The "40" in the command is the lines number.

Comment: Just move the line 4 of `__init__.py` (`import FlaskApp.main`) into `app_context`.

Comment: i dont mean to be a pain but how to do that im new to the app_context

Comment: See my answer. I already updated that according to your stacktrace.

Comment: ok man thanks a lot im still getting a error but is about my database set up i appreciate your  help and quick replies